# HTML/JQuery: Button Only Working Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I have a button that rotates the div, called bacon, 90 degrees.

If I press the button once, the code works, rotating the div 90 degrees.

If I press the button a second time, nothing additional happens.

```
$("#button").on("click", function () {
    $("#bacon").css({
        '-moz-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
        '-webkit-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
        '-o-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
        '-ms-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
        'transform':'rotate(90deg)'
    });
});
```

What I would like the above code to do is to allow me to keep rotating infinitely. So I press it once, it rotates the bacon 90 degrees from the original, twice for 180 degrees from the original, three for 270 degrees from the original, etc.

Thanks.

*Edit: I have a second button called `#button2` that does the same as `#button` except its counter clockwise. When I press `#button` it goes 90 degrees, followed by `#button2` bringing it back to its original, pressing `#button` will work again and make it 90 degrees again.

Basically, after I press a button, only the other one will work subsequently, so I can only alternate between 2 states instead of allowing to rotate fully through all 4 possible states.

Comment: Once it's rotated from 0 to 90, it no longer needs to rotate from 90 to 90. You'd be better off toggling classes on the element and keeping your styles in CSS.

Comment: What do you mean by toggling classes? As in, I'd have one state of bacon at 90, 180, 270, 360(0) rotations and the button would trigger to one of those? (Sorry if misinterpreting, just learning how to code)..Ah someone posted on the bottom, thx anyway

Comment: Actually, I should have said "toggling `[data-*]` attributes", because it would make more sense with something like `[data-rotation="90"]`, `[data-rotation="180"]`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the rotation in a variable, and increment it each time:

```
var cur_rotation = 0;
$("#button").on("click", function() {
    cur_rotation = (cur_rotation + 90) % 360;
    var rot = 'rotate('+cur_rotation+'deg)';
    $("#bacon").css({
        '-moz-transform':rot,
        '-webkit-transform':rot,
        '-ms-transform':rot,
        'transform':rot
    });
});
```

The second button should be the same, except it subtracts 90 instead of adding.

Comment: I understand what the code is doing but its not working. I think I have to put degs after the rotation #, would it be var rot = 'rotate('+cur_rotation+'degs)';

Comment: How about using (cur_rotation + 90) * 2

Comment: @C-Link Why multiply by 2?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use classes:

```
var cls = ['rotate-90', 'rotate-180', 'rotate-270', 'rorate-360'],
      i = 0;

$("#button").on("click", function () {
    $("#bacon").removeClass(cls.join(' ')).addClass(cls[i % cls.length]);
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Ty for the answer. Is there a benefit to using this method vs. the one Barmar posted?

Comment: Well, using this method you put the styles in your stylesheet. I would do this, sometimes there are many ways for doing the same thing ;)